# Sum of TimeSpan in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework-core

I have a View Model for showing my course on the index page

```
public class ShowCourseListItemViewModel
{
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string ImageName { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan TotalTime { get; set; }
}
```

and I have a service for Get All Courses:

```
...
return result.Include(e => e.CourseEpisodes).Select(c => new ShowCourseListItemViewModel()
{
    CourseId = c.CourseId,
    Title = c.CourseTitle,
    ImageName = c.CourseImageName,
    Price = c.CoursePrice,
    TotalTime = new TimeSpan(c.CourseEpisodes.Sum(e => e.EpisodeTime.Ticks)) <== Error is Here
}).Skip(skip).Take(take).ToList();
...
```

Error Text:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
> InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet()
> .Where(c0 => EF.Property<Nullable>(EntityShaperExpression:
> EntityType: Course ValueBufferExpression: ProjectionBindingExpression:
> EmptyProjectionMember IsNullable: False , "CourseId") != null &&
> object.Equals( objA:
> (object)EF.Property<Nullable>(EntityShaperExpression: EntityType:
> Course ValueBufferExpression: ProjectionBindingExpression:
> EmptyProjectionMember IsNullable: False , "CourseId"), objB:
> (object)EF.Property<Nullable>(c0, "CourseId"))) .Sum(c0 =>
> c0.EpisodeTime.Ticks)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the
> query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation
> explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable',
> 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

I think problem is Sum of `TimeSpan`. Any suggestion on this summation?

Comment: Try replacing `c.CourseEpisodes.Sum` by `c.CourseEpisodes.ToList().Sum`.

Comment: If you put `.AsEnumerable()` before `.Select(` you will pull query data to client and then compute `Select` result on client - you may want to put `.Select(c => new { c.CourseId, c.CourseTitle, c.CourseImageName, c.CoursePrice })` before the `Include` to filter the data pulled over to the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to execute the query by calling a method such as `ToList` before doing the `Select` since EF won't know how to convert that part to `SQL`. Try this:

```
return result.Include(e => e.CourseEpisodes).Skip(skip).Take(take).ToList()
.Select(c => new ShowCourseListItemViewModel()
{
    CourseId = c.CourseId,
    Title = c.CourseTitle,
    ImageName = c.CourseImageName,
    Price = c.CoursePrice,
    TotalTime = new TimeSpan(c.CourseEpisodes.Sum(e => e.EpisodeTime.Ticks))
});
```

Answer (score 4):

```
        return result.Include(e => e.CourseEpisodes).AsEnumerable()
            .Select(c => new ShowCourseListItemViewModel()
            {
                CourseId = c.CourseId,
                Title = c.CourseTitle,
                ImageName = c.CourseImageName,
                Price = c.CoursePrice,
                TotalTime = new TimeSpan(c.CourseEpisodes.ToList().Sum(e => e.EpisodeTime.Ticks))
            }).Skip(skip).Take(take).ToList();
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.